# Switch case in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a function that needs to pick out the color of a fruit and I have opted for a *switch* case statement. The problem is I'm not sure how to get the result out of the statement. Maybe I should get an *if*/*else*-statement instead?

Here is the code:

```
function fruitColor(fruit) {
    switch(color) {
        case "apple" : green;
            break;
        case "banana" : yellow;
            break;
        case "kiwi" : green;
            break;
        case "plum" : red;
            break;
    }
}

var result = fruitColor(plum);
```

I can't get the result and I'm not sure if I need a 'return' value or something like that.

Comment: You **definitely** need a `return`, at least one. Without a `return` no JavaScript function can return a value, which is what your last line expects.

Comment: Yeah, `return` is needed in a function where you are setting a value by calling it. If you have a function that simply sets something or logs something, like `console.log("Test")` then a `return` isn't necessarily needed, but since you're trying to set `result` to the value of `fruitColor(plum)`, you need to have the function spit something back at you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller. *[return <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)*

There are a few missteps here aside from not returning a value. `return` is the facility to send a value back from a function, but in order for that to happen, no errors can occur. As it stands, the variable `color` is used in the switch statement, but it does not exist, perhaps because it was supposed to be `fruit` or vice versa. Further, the values in the resulting code for the case statements are basically just references to variables, and if there is no variable named `green` then it is just undefined. Perhaps you meant "green".

```
function fruitColor(fruit) {
 //note that there was no value color here, there was only the accepted
 //parameter fruit, which should either be used or changed to color
 switch(color) {
  case "apple" : 
   //needs quotes, green with no quotes is a variable reference
   "green";
   //note that simply using the string "green" doesn't accomplish anything though
   //what we really need to do is send a value back, and in JavaScript you
   //use the return keyword for that followed by the returning value
   return "green";//like this
    break;
  case "banana" : "yellow";//^
    break;
  case "kiwi" : "green";//^
    break;
  case "plum" : "red";//^
    break;
 }
}
var result = fruitColor("plum");//needs quotes, plum would be a variable refernce
```

Personally, I prefer dictionaries for this type of work.

```
var fruitColors = {
 apple : "green",
 banana : "yellow",
 kiwi : "green",
 plum : "red"
};
var plumColor = fruitColors["plum"];//red
```

Answer (score 4):

When coding, you always want to keep your code as high performance as possible. Now that I said that, let me give you some options to solve problems of this kind:

First, let’s go with your current solution and making it work.

```
function fruitColor(fruit) {
    switch(color) {
        case "apple" :
            return 'green';
            break;
        case "banana" :
            return 'yellow';
            break;
        case "kiwi" :
            return 'green'
            break;
        case "plum" :
            return 'red';
            break;
    }
}

var result = fruitColor(plum);
```

This one uses your switch construct and also returns prematurely, works.

However, it is not the best way to attack these kind of problems, because it generates code bifurcations that imply more memory is used to store and evaluate your code. Another way to do this is using an object with the fruits and colours.

```
function fruitColor(fruit) {
    var fruits = {
        apple  : 'green',
        banana : 'yellow',
        kiwi   : 'green',
        plum   : 'red'
    };
    return fruits[fruit] || 'not found';
}

var result = fruitColor('plum');
```

This code relies in a in-memory data base, works fast and has less bifurcations, but it also depends on a search.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `break` when calling `return` from inside a `case`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my function implementation of the *switch* construct:

```
const fruitColor = fruit =>
  ({ apple: "green", banana: "yellow", kiwi: "green", plum: "red" }[fruit] ||
  "Nothing");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to add a following up to [Travis J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972446/switch-case-in-a-javascript-function/28972575#28972575).

From here I want to emphasise how you can put your arguments into the *switch* statement. The parameter variables `fruit` and `color` takes an argument. If you want an argument taken from the function `fruitColor` into the switch statement, use the same parameter variable name. I.e., either use `fruit` for both, or `color` for both.

```
function fruitColor(fruit) {

    // Note that there was no value color here. There was only the accepted
    // parameter fruit, which should either be used or changed to color
    switch(color) {
        case "apple":
            "green";
            return "green"; // Like this
            break;
        case "banana": "yellow"; // ^
            break;
        case "kiwi": "green"; // ^
            break;
        case "plum": "red"; // ^
            break;
    }
}
var result = fruitColor("plum");
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, in the switch statement, you have got to use the fruit argument, not the color and then you need a variable to store your choice:

```
function fruitColor(fruit) {
    switch(fruit) {
        case "apple" : result = green;
            break;
        case "banana" : result = yellow;
            break;
        case "kiwi" : result = green;
            break;
        case "plum" : result = red;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}

var result = fruitColor(plum);
```

Comment: You're missing a lot of `"`... plum, green, yellow, green and red are undefined (thinks they're variables without `"`)

Comment: I am not missing anything

Comment: You forgot to declare your result variable for one that I can see (in function scope), then you have the colors which are not strings.. you'll get undeclared exceptions.. jsfiddle it, I promise that will fail

Comment: result is a global variable, and then a local variable result is declared again. Also, green, yellow, etc. are treated like objects. You should edit this answer.